# How do I only return part of a string with varying lengths in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with only 1 column that contains a string.  I am trying to only get the email address.  How can I do that?  I looked at Substring/Ltrim, etc, but I haven't been able to piece together how to extract only part of the string.  I am fairly new to SQL.  Thank you for your help!

```
Column1:

John Smith     Email: John.Smith@987456email.com  Terminate:
  
Jacqueline Smith    Email: Jacqueline.Smith@987456email.com     Terminate:
```

Comment: Assuming formatting is consistent, you can look for the first occurrence of a : and terminate and keep the rest.

Comment: Storing data like this in an SQL database isn't optimal. You should _really_ consider splitting the string into name/email/... and insert it as separate fields. As it's formatted now, you don't have much of an advantage compared to - for example - storing the data in a plain text file with fixed row size.

Comment: This data came from an outside source this way and is only going to be used to validate email addresses.  I agree with you @JoachimIsaksson!

Comment: Thank you @xQbert.  I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean, what would the code look like to look for the ':'?  I don't know which function to use.

Comment: See answer below and SQL fiddle for working example.

Comment: I see no reason to downvote it. He's not suggesting to normalize data in this way. He has a problem to solve and it raises interesting thoughts about SQL regex, for example. Sometimes you have to deal with data (most times temporary data originating from an integration) that were not normalized by yourself.

Comment: Could the Downvotes be for not showing any work?

Comment: @Caffé I did not downvote, I know that in practice "real life" does not always coexist well with "ideal life", but thought it was worth a mention.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I hadn't know who downvoted, just saying to him/her, whoever he/she is. And I agree it was worth a mention.

Comment: @xQbert We could know if he/she had told us.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming the email is prefixed by `Email:` and does not contain spaces, you can just take all characters after `Email:` and before the next space (or end of string);

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', a.em) <> 0 
            THEN SUBSTRING(a.em, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', a.em) - 1)
            ELSE a.em END email
FROM (
  SELECT SUBSTRING(column1, CHARINDEX('Email: ', column1) + 7, LEN(column1)) em
  FROM mytable
) a
```

The subquery keeps anything after `Email:` and the outer query cuts everything trailing the next space (or end of string).

The query assumes that there is an `Email:` tag, if that's not guaranteed, you'll want to use a `WHERE` to make sure that only rows that have will be returned.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c8a75/1).

Answer (score 3):

I'm making a few assumptions about your data, namely that the characters 'Name:' don't appear before the name and that each line includes the substring 'Terminate:'

In SQL Server, use a combination of PATINDEX, CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING to parse the address from the string in each row. The cursor lets you loop through your table. This will print out all the e-mail addresses in your table. It needs formatting and if you want to search for a particular person's email, you will have to modify the select statement with a WHERE clause. I hope this helps:

declare @strung as nvarchar(255)
        ,@start as int
        ,@end as int
        ,@result as int
        ,@emailCursor Cursor

set @emailCursor =  CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY STATIC READ_ONLY FOR
                    Select yourColumnName
                    from yourTableName

```
OPEN @emailCursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM @emailCursor INTO @strung
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0    
    BEGIN                   
        set @start = (select charindex(':',@strung)+1);
        set @end = (SELECT PATINDEX('%Terminate:%', @strung)-1)
        set @result = @end-@start
        set @address = (select SUBSTRING(@strung, @start, @result ) AS eMailAddress)
        print @address
    FETCH NEXT FROM @emailCursor INTO @strung                       
    END

CLOSE @emailCursor              
DEALLOCATE @emailCursor
```

CHARINDEX returns the position of the first ':' character in your string (the one after EMAIL). I add one to that value to move you past the ':'

PATINDEX returns the beginning position of the substring 'Terminate'

SUBSTRING returns all the character between the starting position [CHARNINDEX(':', @strung)] and the space before 'Terminate' [PATINDEX('%Terminate:%', @strung)]

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5ce48/8/0

```
select ltrim(rtrim(substring(column1,patindex(column1,':')+1, len(column1)-patindex(column1,':')-11))) as email
from t;
```

assumes Terminate: is consistent and first : denotes end of first characters to remove.

What it does:

1. It uses `SUBSTRING()` to take out a string based on a specific starting character and end character.
2. To determine the start character we look for the first occurrence of : using `PATINDEX()` and add 2 1 for the space, 1 to move to the starting character.  This gives us the starting potion for `SUBSTRING()`
3. To determine how many characters in the `SUBSTRING()` we take the `LEN()` of the entire string subtract from it the length of everything before the first ':' + 1 and the length of ' Terminate:' (11)

Again this HEAVILY assumes consistent formatting.  If it's not ': space' and ' Terminate:' isn't 11 with a space, then this doesn't work.

Comment: The question is tagged SQL Server and your code doesn't look compatible.

Comment: This topic is beyond my current scope, so I appreciate the help.  I ran the code and it gave me some errors and so I researched and replaced some functions, hoping they would work.

    select substring(column1,charindex(column1,':')+2,len(column1)-charindex(column1,':')-11) 
from t;

The query worked, but it did not give me the results I’m expecting.  I applied your example to my live data. 

Now, my data looks like this:  ‘acqueline Ryan Email: Jacqueline.Ryan@987456email.com’

When running it against my entire table, the results varied with different name lengths.

Comment: I amended it to use SQL Server syntax.

Comment: As far as the results I've modiified it to fix the dropped 1st character. but the problem with terminate has to do with inconsistant formatting.  which is what I was afraid of... I can resolve this with a trim and taking a least removal...

Comment: Thanks for all of your help xQbert.

Answer (score 0):

This also works...

```
    declare @data varchar(100) = 'John Smith     Email: John.Smith@987456email.com
    Terminate:'

    select SUBSTRING(@data, PATINDEX('%Email%', @data)+7, PATINDEX('%com%', @data)- 
    PATINDEX('%Email%', @data)-4)
```